Substitution of the old variable to a generating function
Assume that we have one of the 4 types of generating functions (say F(p, Q)) which defines a symplectomorphism $T$:
$(P,Q) = (u(p,q), v(p,q))$. Now we can make a substitution and get a function $G(p,q)$ of old variables $(p,q)$ by formula $G(p,q)= F(p, v(p,q))$.
Questions:

Is there a specific geometric meaning for $G$?
Does $G$ uniquely define $T$ if we know the type (1,2,3,4) of $F$? If not,  what is the ambiguity?
Are $G$-s of 4 types related to each other?

